# Consultas MongoDB utilizando like e desconsiderando acentos e case

Tags: mongodb, operador-like

Gostaria de saber como posso realizar consultas no mongodb ao posso consultar em qualquer posição da string (Like) porém também seria necessário desconsiderar os caracteres especiais como por exemplo acentos.

Consegui desconsiderar nas consultas os caracteres especiais porém o mesmo não realiza busca por partes de uma string. Alguma sugestão de como devo fazer tal consulta?

[image: Coleção]

```
db.pessoas.find({$text: {$search: "jose"})
```

Resultado obtido

[image: Resultado obtido]

Porém queria que fosse retornado o nome ***Joseane*** que contém os caracteres ***jose***

Answer (score -1):

voce pode utilizar regex para fazer a busca:

```
db.getCollection('pessoas').find({ nome: { $in: [ /^Jos/i, /^é/ ] } } )
```